# Uploading Wear OS app with additional mobile app

Tags: android, google-play, wear-os

Im trying to upload a new release to the PlayStore with two bundles:

- Wear os bundle
- Mobile bundle
- I have enabled the wear os track
- I created a new track for "WearOs only"
- I have uses feature "android.hardware.type.watch" in the wear os module manifest
- I DONT have com.google.android.wearable.standalone in the wear os module maifest

Whatever I do I get an error like "APKs or Android App Bundles in this track must require the following features:android.hardware.type.watch"

I just dont seem to understand how to do this, thanks for the help!

All kinds of uploads

Answer (score 1):

First: you watch app requires the "com.google.android.wearable.standalone", set it to true or false.

Second: the phone .aab must go in the phone track and the watch .aab must go in the watch track. According to the error message, seems to me that you are trying to upload the phone .aab in the watch track along with the watch .aab